# Visual Studio 2019 class diagram designer toolbox empty

Tags: c#, c++

I have added a new class diagram file(.cd) to my C++ project in visual studio and when I open the toolbox to design the diagram the toolbox is empty But the strange thing is when I open a C# project the diagram designer isn't empty.

#### C++ toolbox

[image: Image of C++ toolbox]

#### C# toolbox

[image: Image of C# toolbox]

Comment: Isn't Mickesoft the one with C# and the *NIX guys those with C++? Why you think your observation is strange?

Answer (score 0):

Right Click-> Choose items-> Tick all boxes you want -> ok

Maybe you need to go to browse and add windows.forms.dll... butI dont think so.

Comment: I have the same problem and these objects: class, enum, Interface ... and others do not appear ... will they have another name?